# Yii2 - SluggableBehaviour not working on migration

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-behaviors

I have created a migration to insert some data to a table:

$transaction = $this->getDb()->beginTransaction();

```
$widget= \Yii::createObject([
    'class'    => Widget::className(),
    'scenario' => 'create',
    'title' => 'Testimonial',
    'source' => 'testimonial',
    'content'    => ''
]);

if (!$widget->insert(false)) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    return false;
}

$transaction->commit();
```

In model I have configured behavior:

```
'sluggable' => [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'title',
                'ensureUnique' => true
            ]
```

After running the migration slug field is empty. I have other behaviors: Timestamp, Blameable, and Ip they are working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the mystery. SluggableBehavior is triggered "Before Validation", so I just needed to add:

```
"$widget->validate();"
```

Final code:

```
/*Widget*/
        $transaction = $this->getDb()->beginTransaction();

        $widget= \Yii::createObject([
            'class'    => Widget::className(),
            'title' => 'Testimonial',
            'source' => 'testimonial',
            'content'    => ''
        ]);

        $widget->validate();
        if (!$widget->insert(false)) {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            return false;
        }

        $transaction->commit();
```